# equation of 3d curve passing through three points

Tags: 3d, curves, parametric

Let $P=(x_1,y_1,0)$ and $Q=(x_2,y_2,0)$ be two points in the $xy$ plane.

Find an equation for a curve (could be a half-ellipse) passing through $P$, $Q$, and a third point $R=(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2},\frac{y_1+y2}{2},h)$ for some fixed height $h$. It is important that the curve does not extend beyond the $xy$ plane.

It's for an art project. I'm rusty on my 3d curve sketching/describing/parameterization.

I have tried to figure it out with the equations for an ellipse $(x/a)^2+(y/b)^2+(z/c)^2=1$ where one of the minor axes $c$ would be represented by height in the problem and solving for $z$ , taking the positive root to ensure we don't go past the $xy$ plane.

Comment: If I'm not misunderstanding it, your question is a contradiction. If $(x_1,y_1,0)$ and $(x_2,y_2,0)$ both lie in the $xy$ plane, yes. However, $(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2},\frac{y_1+y_2}{2},h)$ does not, so if your curve is to pass through that point, it must not be completely contained in the $xy$ plane. This is assuming that by "$xy$ plane" you are referring to the set of points of the form $(a_x,b_y,0)$; otherwise, I am not sure what you mean when you talk about not wanting to extend past "**the**" $xy$ plane — which one? If my assumption is incorrect, then _any_ set of points of the form (cont)

Comment: (continued) $(a_x,b_y,c)$ for fixed $c$ could be considered "**an**" $xy$ plane.

Comment: What you call an ellipse is not an ellipse, and in fact not a curve at all. Did you mean _surface_, by any chance?

Comment: Nope. I mean curve. And of course point R is not in the xy plane.... by not extending beyond the xy plane I mean the endpoints are on the xy plane....

Comment: I see. You gotta be more exact in your phrasing when dealing with mathematicians lol, since every detail matters. I was genuinely confused, since the notion of "the" $xy$ plane isn't standard by any means

Answer (score 1):

Since the three points in question lie in the vertical plane through $(x_{1}, y_{1}, 0)$ and $(x_{2}, y_{2}, 0)$, one approach is to pick your favorite smooth, non-negative function $\phi$ defined on $[0, 1]$ and satisfying
$$
\phi(0) = \phi(1) = 0,\quad
\phi(1/2) = 1,
$$
and to take your parametric curve to be
$$
t \mapsto \bigl(x_{1} + t(x_{2} - x_{1}), y_{1} + t(y_{2} - y_{1}), h\phi(t)\bigr).
$$

A parabola results from taking $\phi(t) = 4t(1 - t)$. A half-ellipse results from $\phi(t) = 2\sqrt{t(1 - t)}$.